# Relationship between uniform convergence and completeness with $BV([a,b])$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I'm reading Carother's Real Analysis and currently on the chapter about functions of bounded variations on the interval $[a,b]$, that is $BV([a,b])$. I came across the statement below:

"... Thus, $C([a,b])$ is contained in the closure of $BV([a,b])$ under uniform convergence but not in $BV([a,b])$ itself. That is, $BV([a,b])$ is evidently not closed under uniform convergence **(and hence is not complete under uniform convergence)**."

I am assuming the author is working with the Sup Norm.

I don't understand the bolded portion of the statement. Is uniform convergence necessary for completeness in functional spaces? If so, can someone point me in the direction for a proof? I have tried looking online. Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f$ is a function in $C[a,b]$ which is not of bounded variation then there exists a sequence of functions in $BV[a,b]$ ( in fact a sequence of polynomials) converging uniformly to $f$. This sequence in $BV[a,b]$ is a Cauchy sequence. If it converges to some element of $BV[a,b]$ then  this element has to be $f$ but $f$ is not bounded variation. Hence $BV[a,b]$ is not complete.

Comment: fantastic, thank you very much.

Comment: I would like to clarify some reasoning behind your points: Let $f$ $\in$ $C([a,b])$ and $f$ $\notin$ $BV([a,b])$. We can say $\exists$ a sequence $P_{n}$ $\subset$ $\mathcal{P}([a,b])$ s.t $P_{n}$ $\to$ f uniformly by Weiestrass approximation. $\mathcal{P}([a,b])$ $\subset$ $BV([a,b])$ therefore $P_{n}$ $\in$ $BV([a,b])$.  $P_{n}$ $\in$ $BV([a,b])$ s.t $P_{n}$ $\to$ $f$ $\notin$ $BV([a,b])$. We know that $P_{n}$ is cauchy because it is convergent to $f$. Hence, we have a cauchy sequence in $BV([a,b])$ that is not convergent in $BV([a,b])$. Hence, $BV([a,b])$ is not complete.

Comment: @MatteoLepur You are right.

Comment: Thanks again for the prompt reply.